# Do I need to install Yosemite in order to build a Swift iOS app?

Tags: macos, swift

I would like to try building a swift app, but I am afraid to upgrade my Mac to Yosemite Developer Preview.  I am not clear if this is a prerequisite.

Comment: FYI - you cannot submit an iOS app to the App Store if you built it with a beta version of Xcode. Or if you built it on a beta version of OS X!! Just a note for anyone else who runs across this question. There are people right now who were (often without realizing it) enrolled in the OS X beta program, and are now running 10.11.5 beta from an automatic update. They can't submit any apps, and you can't downgrade from the beta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just to get the official source in here, the [Xcode 6 Beta 1 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2014/xcode_6_beta_ie8g3n/xcode_6_beta_release_notes.pdf) state:

> Xcode 6 Beta requires a Mac running OS X version 10.9.3 (or later) or 10.10.

And Xcode 6 comes bundled with Swift.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a prerequisite. You can install the XCode 6 beta which includes swift support as long as you have the newest version of Mavericks (10.9.3)

Answer (score 1):

No. I am using Mavericks (10.9.3), and Xcode6 beta is working well, and built program is also working well.